# In Visual Studio 2015 readonly automatic properties can be set and it builds! Is this a bug?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

This code

```
public class Entity
{
    public string First { get; }
    public string Last { get; }
    public Entity()
    {
        this.First = "First name";
        this.Last = "Last name";
    }
}
```

Will compile in VS2015 yet VS2013 gives errors "Property or indexer 'ScottRickman.Entity.First' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"

Is this a bug in VS2015?

Comment: This is a [new feature of C#6.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6.aspx) ("Getter-only auto-properties"), which is supported by VS2015, but not by VS2013 (at least not out of the box).

Comment: These are called "Getter Only auto-properties", and they are valid syntax in C# 6.0

Comment: Grx70, thanks! Make this an answer and I'll mark it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a new [feature of C# 6.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6.aspx) (see section "Getter-only auto-properties"). By default VS2015 uses C# 6.0 compiler, while VS2013 uses C# 5.0 compiler, hence the compile time error occurs only in VS2013.

Comment: I set language version in project settings to 5.0. But this code still compiles...

Comment: @AlexanderNechay You're right, I myself also find it quite peculiar. Take a  look at [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4ckecs0.aspx) though - it states that changing that option does not result in using other versions of the compiler, but rather in passing an option to the actual compiler, which "does not give you the equivalent functionality of an earlier version of the compiler".